How to add horizontal gauge chart on muix charts?
I am trying to create a horizontal gauge chart using muix chart library. Attached is the type that exists on mui chart and the one I am trying to create.
Gauge chart from muix charts
Horizontal gauge chart I am trying to implement on muix chart
Link to gauge chart that exists in mui 
I have tried to modify the startAngle or endAngle properties of gauge charts but the charts are still circular and don't really help to achieve wat I am trying to get.

Update. From mui forum, this solution was given https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w8kgna-8ihauf?file=Demo.js
Adding for anyone looking for a similar solution.
This was solved by using BarChart from muix/charts
